# How to convert CSV file which having both comma and space delimiter to csv with only space delimiter

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, converters

I am trying to convert the last column containing 2 values in the comma-separated form to 2 separate columns. Please see the last columns of input and output file to understand the motive.

Below is how my **input file** looks like:

```
fILENAME sent_no    word POS lab,Slab
File_1   sentence:1  abc NNP B,NO   
                     fhj PSP O,O    
                     bmm NNP B,NO   
                     vbn PSP O,O    
                     vbn NN  B,NO   
                     vbn NNPC B,NO  
                     .  Sym O,O 
File_1   Sentence:2 vbb NNP B,NO    
                    bbn PSP B,NO    
                    nnm NNP O,O 
                    nnn PSP B,NO    
                    bbn NN  O,O 
                    .   Sym O,O
```

and output the **output file** I expect is as below:

```
Filename sent_num word POS Label Slab
 File_1 sentence:1 abc NNP B     NO
                   fhj PSP O      O
                   bmm NNP B     NO
                   vbn PSP O      O
                   vbn NN B      NO
                   vbn NNPC B    NO
                   .   Sym O      O
 File_1 Sentence:2 vbb NNP B     NO
                   bbn PSP B     NO
                   nnm NNP O      O
                   nnn PSP B     NO
                   bbn NN  O      O
                   .   Sym O      O
```

Comment: Could you show the file using any text editor(notepad++, notepad,atom etc..) rather than excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('try.csv',sep=';')
df[['Label','Slabel']]=df['Label,Slabel'].str.split(',',expand=True)
df.drop(['Label,Slabel'],axis=1,inplace=True)
df.to_csv('try2.csv',sep=';')
```

but i see your data using multiindex dataframe, so I add this:

```
df.set_index(['Filename','Sentence_num'],inplace=True)
```

and the result :

```
>>> df
                       Word  POS Label Slabel
Filename Sentence_num                        
File_1   sentence:1     abc  NNP     B     NO
         sentence:1     fhj  PSP     O      O
         sentence:1     bmm  NNP     B     NO
         sentence:1     vbn  PSS     O      O
File_2   sentence:2     vbb  NNP     B     NO
         sentence:2     bbn  PSP     B     NO
         sentence:2     nnm  NNP     O      O
         sentence:2    nnnm  PSP     B     NO
>>>
```

in simple way, you can just using multi separator like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pandas.read_csv('try.csv',sep=' |,', engine='python') # separator space and comma
```

Comment: why did you used ";" seperator in this line df = pandas.read_csv('try.csv',sep=';')

Comment: @pooja . I assume csv file has create using excel, so I using ';' because excel will using this separator.

Comment: if   all column in csv file with comma delimiter  convert to space delimiter  then  i have to specify all column name or  is dere any other way

Comment: @pooja if all columns in csv file with comma delimiter in csv file look like `fILENAME,sent_no,word,POS,lab,Slab` and just change the separator to ',' in line `df = pandas.read_csv('try.csv',sep=',')`. or if you want to using multi separator just change `sep=';'`with `sep= ' |,'` (using space and comma separator)

Comment: I also used this below code to change the comma delimiter csv file to space dellimiter csv file:
import csv

    with open(filename1) as in, open(filename2, 'w') as out:
    out.write(in.read().replace(",", " "))
 but index column : value are 0,1,2,3 how they are removed from file . by using panda or any other way using csv module?

Comment: @pooja if index value column on first column, just add `index_col=[0]` to `df = pandas.read_csv('try.csv',sep=';',index_col=[0])`. for save the file without default index (0,1,2,...) on csv, just add `index=False` to `df.to_csv('try2.csv',sep=';',index=False)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas to separate the 'comma-separated' column into two columns.

Here is an example dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['a,b'], ['c,d']], columns=['Label,Slabel'])
```

It looks like this

```py
    Label,Slabel
0   a,b
1   c,d
```

Then you can convert the values into a list and then into a Series.

```py
df['Label,Slabel'].str.split(',').apply(pd.Series)
```

The result

```
    0   1
0   a   b
1   c   d
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the *.csv file is

```
word POS lab,Slab
abc NNP B,NO
fhj PSP O,O
bmm NNP B,NO
vbn PSP O,O
vbn NN B,NO
vbn NNPC B,NO
vbb NNP B,NO
bbn PSP B,NO
nnm NNP O,O
nnn PSP B,NO
bbn NN O,O
. Sym O,O
```

You can use csv to read and write a specific delimiter csv file.

```
import csv
with open(path, newline='') as csvf:
    rows = csv.reader(csvf, delimiter=' ')
    with open(new_path, 'w', newline='') as new_csvf:
        writer = csv.writer(new_csvf, delimiter=' ')
        for row in rows:
            slab = row[-1].split(',')[-1]
            row.append(slab)
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: if all column in csv file with comma delimiter convert to space delimiter then i have to specify all column name or is dere any other way  and  why did you use delimiter =' ' when reading csv file becauseit is mix of that

Comment: with open(filename1) as infile, open(filename2, 'w') as outfile:
       print(infile.read())
       outfile.write(infile.read().replace(",", " "))    I have written this code to convert  csv file with comma separated file  to space separated file. but values in infile.read() printed  output is ,",F,i,l,e,n,a,m,e,",",S,e,n,t,e,n,c,e,_,n,u,m,",",W,o,r,d,",",P,O,S,",",M,E,N,T,_,L,a,b,e,l,",",S,I,N,G,L,E,_,M,E,N,T,I,O,N
0,",",f,u,l,l,n,e,w,s,_,i,d,_,2,7,1,.,s,s,f,",",s,e,n,t,e,n,c,e,:,1,",",च,ि,ं,त,ा,",",N,N,",",B,-,M,E,N,T,",",N,O
 why am I getting this?